# Retrieving paginated results from PHP Facebook SDK using cursors

Tags: php, facebook, pagination, cursor

Having some issues with the Facebook API and paginated results with cursors. My function keeps returning 25, the original set amount.

```
function buildCampaignsArray($cursor, $campaigns = []) {
    if ($cursor && (int) $cursor->count() > 0) {
        foreach ($cursor as $campaign) {
            $campaigns[] = $campaign;
        }
        return buildCampaignsArray($cursor->next($cursor), $campaigns);
    } else {
        return $campaigns;
    }
}

$account = new \FacebookAds\Object\AdAccount('act_1589583164658726');

$campaigns = buildCampaignsArray(
    $account->getCampaigns(array(
        CampaignFields::NAME,
        CampaignFields::OBJECTIVE,
    ), array(
        CampaignFields::EFFECTIVE_STATUS => array(
            ArchivableCrudObjectEffectiveStatuses::ACTIVE,
            ArchivableCrudObjectEffectiveStatuses::PAUSED,
        ),
    ))
);

var_dump($campaigns); exit;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$campaigns = buildCampaignsArray(
    $account->getCampaigns(array(
        CampaignFields::NAME,
        CampaignFields::OBJECTIVE,
    ), array(
        CampaignFields::EFFECTIVE_STATUS => array(
            ArchivableCrudObjectEffectiveStatuses::ACTIVE,
            ArchivableCrudObjectEffectiveStatuses::PAUSED,
        ),
    ),
['limit' => 100]
)
);
```